# Ubuntu 12.04 beta Compiz error: `Fatal: couldn't open display :0`

Tags: 12.04, display

I'm getting the following error after upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 beta. Even with daily patch updates, it hasn't resolved itself so I'm putting it out there.

Ubuntu 12.04 beta Compiz error: `Fatal: couldn't open display :0`

Basically: When i boot up, the screen shows the Ubuntu loading briefly, for a seconds and then drops to a terminal login screen.

I have an ATI card, used to have my own compiled driver installed on 11.10, not sure if that was overwritten by the upgrade.

## update

when trying to install the `fglrx` driver I get an error similar to this: (I can't screenshot or copy paste in the console, so I'm writing it out on a different computer:

> dpkg: error processing
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>
> subprocess error satus 1

#### update 2

gedit /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log

```
> *** AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Uninstall Log 2012-04-23 14:02:52 *** Forcing uninstall. Removed
> /usr/share/applications/amdcccle.desktop Removed
> /usr/share/applications/amdccclesu.desktop Removed
> /usr/share/icons/ccc_large.xpm md5sum integrity check failed.  Force
> option removes /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_cs.qm md5sum integrity
> check failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_da_DK.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_de.qm
> md5sum integrity check failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_el_GR.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_es_ES.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_fi_FI.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_fr_FR.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_hu_HU.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_it_IT.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ja.qm
> md5sum integrity check failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ko_KR.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_nl_NL.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_no.qm
> md5sum integrity check failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_pl.qm md5sum integrity check failed. 
> Force option removes /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_pt_BR.qm md5sum
> integrity check failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ru_RU.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_sv_SE.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_th.qm
> md5sum integrity check failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_tr_TR.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_zh_CN.qm md5sum integrity check
> failed.  Force option removes
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_zh_TW.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_de.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_es.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_fr.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_ja_JP.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_pl.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_pt.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_ru.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_sv.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_zh_CN.qm Removed
> /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_zh_TW.qm Installed file is missing from
> system /usr/bin/amdcccle. Removed /usr/bin/amdxdg-su Removed
> /usr/bin/amdupdaterandrconfig Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/ccc_copyrights.txt Removed
> /etc/security/console.apps/amdcccle-su Removed
> /usr/share/ati/lib64/libQtCore.so.4 Removed
> /usr/share/ati/lib64/libQtGui.so.4 Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/LICENSE.TXT Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/user-manual/index.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/examples/etc/init.d/atieventsd.sh Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/examples/etc/acpi/ati-powermode.sh Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/examples/etc/acpi/events/a-ac-aticonfig Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/examples/etc/acpi/events/a-lid-aticonfig Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/1gbhang.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4461.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4462.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4463.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4464.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4469.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4470.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4475.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4478.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4479.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4480.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4481.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4482.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4483.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4484.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4485.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/corruptstereo.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/corruptvtswitch.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/devshm.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/dga3dhang.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/doom3corrupt.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/dualheadvideo.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/laptopsuspend.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/missingdrmheaders.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/mousecursorhang.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/no3d-aiw8500dv.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/no3d-kt400.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/nomembercount.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/pcie3dmemoryleak.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/r420blankdisplay.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/rv280dviblankdisplay.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/rv350springdale.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/secondheadcorruption.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/xf86_enodev.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/xrestartpcie.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/xvsatshift.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/configure.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/driverfaq.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/index.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/installer.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/issues.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/linuxfaq.html Removed
> /usr/share/doc/ati/tips-linux.html Removed
> /usr/share/man/man8/atieventsd.8 Removed
> /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so Removed
> /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so Removed
> /usr/lib/xorg/modules/glesx.so Removed /usr/lib/xorg/modules/amdxmm.so
> Removed /usr/lib32/libAMDXvBA.cap Removed /usr/lib32/libAMDXvBA.so.1.0
> Removed /usr/lib32/libOpenCL.so.1 Removed
> /usr/lib32/libSlotMaximizerAg.so Removed
> /usr/lib32/libSlotMaximizerBe.so Removed /usr/lib32/libXvBAW.so.1.0
> Removed /usr/lib32/libamdocl32.so Removed /usr/lib32/libatiadlxx.so
> Removed /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so Removed /usr/lib32/libaticaldd.so
> Removed /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so Removed /usr/lib32/libatiuki.so.1.0
> Removed /usr/lib32/libfglrx_dm.a Removed /usr/lib32/libfglrx_dm.so.1.0
> Removed /usr/lib32/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2 Removed
> /usr/lib/fglrx/switchlibGL Removed /usr/lib/fglrx/switchlibglx Removed
> /usr/lib32/dri/fglrx_dri.so Removed
> /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/fglrx/fglrx-libglx.so Removed
> /usr/lib/libAMDXvBA.cap Removed /usr/lib/libAMDXvBA.so.1.0 Removed
> /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1 Removed /usr/lib/libSlotMaximizerAg.so Removed
> /usr/lib/libSlotMaximizerBe.so Removed /usr/lib/libXvBAW.so.1.0
> Removed /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so Removed /usr/lib/libatiadlxx.so
> Removed /usr/lib/libaticalcl.so Removed /usr/lib/libaticaldd.so
> Removed /usr/lib/libaticalrt.so Removed /usr/lib/libatiuki.so.1.0
> Removed /usr/lib/libfglrx_dm.a Removed /usr/lib/libfglrx_dm.so.1.0
> Removed /usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2 Removed
> /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so Removed /usr/include/GL/glATI.h Removed
> /usr/include/GL/glxATI.h Removed /usr/include/ATI/GL/glx.h Removed
> /usr/include/ATI/GL/glxext.h Removed /usr/bin/fgl_glxgears Removed
> /usr/bin/fglrxinfo Removed /usr/bin/aticonfig Removed
> /usr/bin/atiodcli Removed /usr/bin/atiode Removed /usr/bin/clinfo
> Removed /usr/src/ati/fglrx_sample_source.tgz Removed
> /usr/sbin/amdnotifyui Removed /usr/sbin/atieventsd Removed
> /usr/sbin/atigetsysteminfo.sh Removed /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
> Removed /etc/ati/atiogl.xml Removed /etc/ati/authatieventsd.sh Removed
> /etc/ati/control Removed /etc/ati/logo.xbm.example Removed
> /etc/ati/logo_mask.xbm.example Removed /etc/ati/signature Removed
> /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd Removed
> /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd /usr/bin/md5sum:
> /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: No such file or directory
> /usr/bin/md5sum: /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: No such
> file or directory /usr/bin/md5sum: /usr/bin/amdconfig: No such file or
> directory Removed /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx.conf
```

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: but I can't 'continue' because it is trying to open a browser session... hopefully the relevant info has been sent nonetheless.

Comment: You should probably reask a new question about the AMD driver problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to force uninstall it. There seemed to have been some checksum issues and it didn't want to uninstall it automatically. I have regained a basic GUI access, with the Gallium driver, but still haven't been able to get the ATI driver working. I'll keep trying.